# Remote wipe data using Device Administrator Application+ android

Tags: android

I am working on android device policies, i am able to  implement wipe data, force lock using sample given at below link
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html. I am not able understand how to wipe, force lock, change pwd Remotly from server. I spent lot of time in searching to get information but i am not suceed. Please give any information to implement policies Remotely.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've googled around a bit today as well, and I've come up with the following solution:

First, write a device administrator app, like the one referenced in the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) you provided.

Then you will have to implement some technique so that you can push messages from a server to the android client. As of Android 2.2, you can use [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) (Cloud to device messaging) provided by Google, I guess it isn't to hard to configure and get going. If you do not want to use this, there is the option to use some other kind of messaging framework, that allows you to push data, like [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) or [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/). The facebook messenger app for iOS uses MQTT, so that can't be all bad. It will however require more work setting up, than C2DM for example.

Finally you will have to push some kind of message from your server to the client via the method you chose and let your device administrator app listen to these messages and respond with the correct action, depending on message. So you can decide on your own what the messages will look like and contain.

There is also the option of using Exchange, but I do not know how that works.

So that is basically what I found out from my little research, I'd love to hear other ideas from someone else as well.

Comment: Thank you, very good advice I got some sample from link to implement C2DM http://www.vogella.de/code/code.html, but still i am not clear how we can enforce policies using C2DM, kindly give any explanation.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to directly enforce policies remotely. That is why you will have to write an application that enforces policies locally on the phone. Then you will have to implement some kind of message service (C2DM for example) that you can use to send messages to your policy-application on the phone. The message can be anything, you decide. The application receives the message from C2DM and depending on what the message says, let the app enforce one or another policy. Was that more clear?